# Removing ticks from scale_fill_gradientn colorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've the following code I'm working with:

```
colVec = c(heat.colors(100), "#828282")
colVec = rev(colVec)

remove_axes <- theme(
  axis.text = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank()
)
maineMap <- me_base + 
  geom_polygon(data = graphData, aes(fill = infProp), color = "white") +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) +
  theme_bw() +
  remove_axes

breakVec = seq(0,1,by=0.01)
labelVec = rep("",length(breakVec))
labelVec[1] = 0
labelVec[length(labelVec)] = 1
labelVec[floor(length(labelVec)/2)] = 0.5

countyMap <- maineMap + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colVec, 
                       breaks = breakVec, 
                       limits = c(0, 1), 
                       labels = labelVec)

countyMap
```

Which produces the following image:

[image]

My question is how do I remove all the tick bars on the color bar, and only place them at the points 0, 0.5, and 1? Additionally, can I make the colorbar appear differently, such as thicker or in a different format?

Comment: Does having `breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1)` + `labels = c(0, 0.5, 1)` in `scale_fill_gradientn()` yield what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you